# Who zoomed the video camera in and out when David Scott dropped the feather and hammer on the Moon?

Tags: nasa, apollo-program, photography, apollo-15

[This answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/34311/12102) to *Have optical zoom systems been used in space exploration?* explains that there were video cameras on the Moon that could zoom.

In the video below someone (or something) is zooming the camera showing Commander David Scott in the classic demonstration of dropping a feather and a hammer in the vacuum of space. Was this being done by an astronaut or by remote control from Earth?

---

(NASA source for video: [Apollo 15 Hammer-Feather Drop](https://youtu.be/oYEgdZ3iEKA?t=36))

Hammer vs Feather - Physics on the Moon Apollo 15 (cued at `00:36`)

> Courtesy: NASA - Galileo and Apollo 15. At the end of the last Apollo 15 moon walk, Commander David Scott (pictured above) performed a live demonstration for the television cameras. He held out a geologic hammer and a feather and dropped them at the same time.

Comment: The writeup on this in the *Preliminary Science Reports* is gold: " Within the accuracy of the simultaneous release, the objects were observed to undergo the same acceleration and strike the lunar surface simultaneously,  which was a  result predicted by well-established theory, . but a result nonetheless reassuring considering both the number of viewers that witnessed the experiment and the fact that the homeward journey was based critically on the validity of the particular theory being tested."

Comment: @OrganicMarble Sorry if this is off-topic but I would love to have the source for that quote. It is awesome.

Comment: @Swike no problem! https://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/a15/as15psr.pdf page 2-11

Comment: @OrganicMarble Beautiful. Thank you

Comment: Stanley Kubrick.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm I just posted then quickly deleted "Did Kubrick ever zoom" in Movies SE, apparently he used it quite effectively! Another  Kubrick sighting here in Space SE: [Stanley Kubrick used a NASA-inspired lens to film by candlelight in Barry Lyndon, but what did NASA use it for?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/37975/12102)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Ed Fendell, a controller in Houston was controlling the rover camera.

It’s in the EVA-3 mission logs.

[image]

https://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/a15/a15.clsout3.html

Comment: The control of the camera from Houston must have been delayed by 1.3 seconds, right?

Comment: Yes, but I suspect they practiced. The ascent video was always lagging behind, but this camera work look so good I think it lead to the question.

Comment: Oh! Now this sounds familliar, so I started searching old questions and found that Ed Fendell is also the answer to [How did NASA get the video camera on the Moon to track the LM ascent stage, considering the substantial delay?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/33233/12102) I'd totally forgotten about that question.

Comment: Houston says"Drop it ...now!"  and starts zooming.  Instructions to the astronaut and to the camera get there simultaneously...

Comment: @DJohnM I don't hear anyone say that - at what time, exactly? Lags and delays would depend on which end the recording was made. If the tape is recording on the moon with Houston's voice coming on over radio, then an instruction from Houston would be simultaneous with the action on the Moon (the astronaut would hear the instruction at the same time as it gets recorded). Responses _from_ Houston would be time-delayed. If the recording is happening on Earth, it would be the other way about.

Comment: @OscarBravo More likely each feed was recorded on separate channels of audio tape for later analysis (ie, evidence) so that small details on one wouldn't be hidden by louder audio events on other inputs.  Later, it would be trivial to mix the two sources offset into a final recording that timed up with the footage.